# JQuery: показ цепочки диалогов

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Сразу хочу сказать, что опыт работы с jQuery у меня небольшой, и поэтому заранее прошу извинить меня, если мой вопрос покажется вам элементарным.

Проблема следующая. Клиенту нужно показать цепочку диалогов. Например, в первом диалоге три кнопки: ОК, Продолжить и Отказ. При нажатии на "Продолжить" первый диалог должен закрываться, а вместо него открываться другой и так далее по цепочке.

Насколько я понимаю, диалоги в jQuery-UI асинхронные, но, может, существует какой-то способ решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 1):

[@Hermann Zheboldov](/users/28283/hermann-zheboldov), есть отдельные плагины типа "wizard", надеюсь [это то](http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/wizard/DefaultWizardPage?1), что вы ищете

Comment: К сожалению, немного не то. Смотрю в сторону ExtJS, но этот фреймворк платный...

Comment: @Hermann Zheboldov, ты не шутить? Ты сам указал jquery и jquery-ui теги и в названии jQuery и в начале упомянул jquery. Внизу ответил вообще под jQuery Mobile. При чем тут ExtJS??????

Comment: Ищу любые решения

Comment: Софт, который пишется, изначально был на JS с небольшими добавками jQuery. Сейчас возникла задача этих самых цепочек диалогов. Вот и ищу решение.

Comment: Все, вопрос снят. Все оказалось очень просто, сделал средствами jQuery